# How to draw a horizontal line(based on a certain y-value/level) on a chart and create a legend for it (VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, charts, line, legend

Assume we have a column chart in an excel sheet(for example the chart of students scores) and we want to draw few horizontal lines(for class and school averages) on it based on some cell values and then create a legend for them bottom of the chart by VBA (take a look at the problem image)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNzVW.png).
As far as I know for adding a line to an existing chart we use the following code:

```
...
Dim sh As Shape
Dim ch As Chart
...
Set ch = sh.Chart
...
ch.Shapes.AddConnector(Type:=msoConnectorStraight, BeginX:=150, _
        BeginY:=150, EndX:=200, EndY:=200).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Line
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .Weight = 1.25
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
    End With
...
```

My 1st question is basically how should we adjust the BeginX, BeginY, EndX, EndY parameters to accommodate with the chart vertical axis scale and to place in the level we want.
My 2nd question is how to build the legend, because clearly it couldn't be built normally.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1265-excel-add-average-line-to-chart.html

Comment: @AxelRichter Great! Thanks you really helped me.